# Java Image Cropping Not Accurate

Tags: java, image, crop

Heres my code, when you select and area you want to crop and then push enter, the cropped image isn't the same size/picture as the original selected area.

```
public class DragNDrop extends JFrame implements DropTargetListener {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1872019741456690593L;

private Graphics g;
private BufferedImage image, origiImage;
private Rectangle area;
private Rectangle currentRect;
private Rectangle rectToDraw = null;
private Image buffer;

public static void main(String args[]) {
    new DragNDrop();
}

public DragNDrop() {
    super("Drop Test");
    setSize(300, 300);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setDropTarget(new DropTarget(getContentPane(), this));
    setVisible(true);

    CaptureListener listener = new CaptureListener();
    addMouseListener(listener);
    addMouseMotionListener(listener);
}

public void drop(DropTargetDropEvent dtde) {
    try {
        Transferable tr = dtde.getTransferable();
        DataFlavor[] flavors = tr.getTransferDataFlavors();
        dtde.acceptDrop(DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY_OR_MOVE);
        Object list = tr.getTransferData(flavors[0]);
    list = list.toString().substring(1, list.toString().length()-1);
        if (isValidImage(list)) {
            Image droppedImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(list.toString());
            image = toBufferedImage(droppedImage);
            origiImage = toBufferedImage(droppedImage);
            area = new Rectangle(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
            if (droppedImage != null) {
                setSize(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
                dtde.dropComplete(true);
                addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                        if (e.getKeyCode() == 10) {
                            capture();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

                    }
                });
                return;
            }
        }
        dtde.rejectDrop();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        dtde.rejectDrop();
    }
}

public void paint() {
    if (area != null && image != null) {
        g.clearRect(area.x, area.y, area.width, area.height);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    }
    if (currentRect != null) {
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawRect(rectToDraw.x, rectToDraw.y, rectToDraw.width, rectToDraw.height);
        g.setColor(new Color(255,255,255,150));
        g.fillRect(rectToDraw.x, rectToDraw.y, rectToDraw.width, rectToDraw.height);
    }
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics gr) {
    if (buffer == null && area != null) {
        this.buffer = createImage(area.width, area.height);
        this.g = buffer.getGraphics();
    }
    paint();
    if (buffer != null)
        gr.drawImage(buffer, 0, 0, this);
}

public boolean isValidImage(Object list) {
    System.out.println(list.toString());
    for (String string : ImageIO.getReaderFormatNames())
        if (list.toString().contains(string))
            return true;
    return false;
}

public BufferedImage toBufferedImage(Image image) {
    if (image instanceof BufferedImage) {
        return (BufferedImage) image;
    }
    image = new ImageIcon(image).getImage();
    boolean hasAlpha = hasAlpha(image);
    BufferedImage bimage = null;
    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    int transparency = Transparency.OPAQUE;
    if (hasAlpha == true) {
        transparency = Transparency.BITMASK;
    }
    GraphicsDevice gs = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
    GraphicsConfiguration gc = gs.getDefaultConfiguration();
    bimage = gc.createCompatibleImage(image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null), transparency);
    if (bimage == null) {
        int type = BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB;
        if (hasAlpha == true) {
            type = BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB;
        }
        bimage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null), type);
    }
    Graphics g = bimage.createGraphics();
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    g.dispose();
    return bimage;
}

public static boolean hasAlpha(Image image) {
    if (image instanceof BufferedImage) {
        return ((BufferedImage) image).getColorModel().hasAlpha();
    }
    PixelGrabber pg = new PixelGrabber(image, 0, 0, 1, 1, false);
    try {
        pg.grabPixels();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
    return pg.getColorModel().hasAlpha();
}

private void updateRectangle(int compWidth, int compHeight) {
    int x = currentRect.x;
    int y = currentRect.y;
    int width = currentRect.width;
    int height = currentRect.height;
    if (width < 0) {
        width = 0 - width;
        x = x - width + 1;
        if (x < 0) {
            width += x;
            x = 0;
        }
    }
    if (height < 0) {
        height = 0 - height;
        y = y - height + 1;
        if (y < 0) {
            height += y;
            y = 0;
        }
    }
    if ((x + width) > compWidth) {
        width = compWidth - x;
    }
    if ((y + height) > compHeight) {
        height = compHeight - y;
    }
    if (rectToDraw != null) {
        rectToDraw.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
    } else {
        rectToDraw = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
    }
}

public void capture() {
    BufferedImage croppedImage = origiImage.getSubimage(rectToDraw.x, rectToDraw.y, rectToDraw.width, rectToDraw.height);
    setSize(rectToDraw.width, rectToDraw.height);
    image = croppedImage;
}

public void upload(BufferedImage image) {
    String IMGUR_POST_URI = "http://api.imgur.com/2/upload.xml";
    String IMGUR_API_KEY = "b84e430b4a65d16a6955358141f21a61";
    String readLine = null;
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", outputStream);
        URL url = new URL(IMGUR_POST_URI);

        String data = URLEncoder.encode("image", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Base64.encodeBase64String(outputStream.toByteArray()).toString(), "UTF-8") + "&" + URLEncoder.encode("key", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(IMGUR_API_KEY, "UTF-8");

        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(data);
        wr.flush();
        // Get the response
        InputStream inputStream;
        if (((HttpURLConnection) urlConnection).getResponseCode() == 400) {
            inputStream = ((HttpURLConnection) urlConnection).getErrorStream();
        } else {
            inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        }
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            readLine = line;
        }
        wr.close();
        reader.close();
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //Prints the url link of the image uploaded
    System.out.println(readLine.substring(readLine.indexOf("<original>") + 10, readLine.indexOf("</original>")));
}

public void dragEnter(DropTargetDragEvent dtde) {

}

public void dragExit(DropTargetEvent dte) {

}

public void dragOver(DropTargetDragEvent dtde) {

}

public void dropActionChanged(DropTargetDragEvent dtde) {

}

private class CaptureListener extends MouseInputAdapter {
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        updateSize(e);
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        int x = e.getX();
        int y = e.getY();
        currentRect = new Rectangle(x, y, 0, 0);
        updateRectangle(getWidth(), getHeight());
        repaint();
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        updateSize(e);
    }

    public void updateSize(MouseEvent e) {
        currentRect.setSize(e.getX() - currentRect.x, e.getY() - currentRect.y);
        updateRectangle(getWidth(), getHeight());
        repaint();
    }
}

}
```

Can someone look through my code and find why it doesn't crop the exact same size?

Comment: Could you please provide a **minimal** example for the problem you are having? For instance a short program that just takes a picture and crops a specified area. Asking others to debug your whole code is neither good style nor the way to get helpful answers soon.

Comment: As you can see here, here is the area I selected.
http://i.imgur.com/2uwzD.jpg

And here is the outcome.
http://i.imgur.com/dhTOU.png

Comment: Screenshots are a good idea. They gave me a first hint of what might be wrong. However, this was not what I meant by 'minimal example'. I rather thought of a smaller version of your program illustrating just the problem. There is a lot of code in your program that is not related to the cropping issue. I hope it becomes a bit clearer in my answer. Let me know if it helps you (and ask if anything is unclear).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your cropping logic, the problem is with you paint logic.

Firstly, you should never (okay, rearly) override `paint` on a top level container (like a `JFrame`).  There are lots of reasons and you just discovered one of them.

Secondly, you should ALWAYS call `super.paintXxx(g)`, not doing so is a REALLY bad idea.

To be honest, I've got no idea of what half this code is trying to do (other then double buffering), which wouldn't be required if you used something like `JPanel`

```
public void paint() {
    if (area != null && image != null) {
        g.clearRect(area.x, area.y, area.width, area.height);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    }
    if (currentRect != null) {
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawRect(rectToDraw.x, rectToDraw.y, rectToDraw.width, rectToDraw.height);
        g.setColor(new Color(255,255,255,150));
        g.fillRect(rectToDraw.x, rectToDraw.y, rectToDraw.width, rectToDraw.height);
    }
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics gr) {
    if (buffer == null && area != null) {
        this.buffer = createImage(area.width, area.height);
        this.g = buffer.getGraphics();
    }
    paint();
    if (buffer != null)
        gr.drawImage(buffer, 0, 0, this);
}
```

This doesn't allow for the fact that the frame is actually leaving space for the frames decorations (0x0 is actually the very top left hand corner of the window, not the inner drawing surface)...

So I've taken to you're code and rewritten it...

```
public class DragNDrop extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1872019741456690593L;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new DragNDrop();
    }

    public DragNDrop() {
        super("Drop Test");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new ImagePane());
        setSize(300, 300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    protected class ImagePane extends JPanel implements DropTargetListener {

        private BufferedImage image, origiImage;
        private Rectangle currentRect;
        private Rectangle rectToDraw = null;

        public ImagePane() {

            setDropTarget(new DropTarget(getContentPane(), this));
            CaptureListener listener = new CaptureListener();
            addMouseListener(listener);
            addMouseMotionListener(listener);

            setFocusable(true);
            requestFocusInWindow();

            // Keybindings are better the KeyListeners, as the generally work...
            InputMap im = getInputMap(WHEN_FOCUSED);
            ActionMap am = getActionMap();

            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0), "Capture");
            am.put("Capture", new AbstractAction() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    capture();
                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            // Look how simple this is...

            super.paintComponent(g);

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            if (image != null) {
                g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
            }

            if (currentRect != null) {
                g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
                g2d.drawRect(rectToDraw.x, rectToDraw.y, rectToDraw.width, rectToDraw.height);
                g2d.setColor(new Color(255, 255, 255, 150));
                g2d.fillRect(rectToDraw.x, rectToDraw.y, rectToDraw.width, rectToDraw.height);
            }
        }

        public void drop(DropTargetDropEvent dtde) {
            try {
                Transferable tr = dtde.getTransferable();
                DataFlavor[] flavors = tr.getTransferDataFlavors();
                dtde.acceptDrop(DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY_OR_MOVE);
                Object list = tr.getTransferData(flavors[0]);
                list = list.toString().substring(1, list.toString().length() - 1);
                if (isValidImage(list)) {
                    Image droppedImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(list.toString());
                    image = toBufferedImage(droppedImage);
                    origiImage = toBufferedImage(droppedImage);
                    if (droppedImage != null) {
                        setSize(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
                        dtde.dropComplete(true);
                        // This is a bad idea, apart from KeyListeners are just a bad idea,
                        // Each time you drop a new image, your registering a new key listener :P
//                        addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
//                            @Override
//                            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
//                            }
//
//                            @Override
//                            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
//                                if (e.getKeyCode() == 10) {
//                                    capture();
//                                }
//                            }
//
//                            @Override
//                            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
//                            }
//                        });
                        return;
                    }
                }
                dtde.rejectDrop();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                dtde.rejectDrop();
            }
        }

        public boolean isValidImage(Object list) {
            System.out.println(list.toString());
            for (String string : ImageIO.getReaderFormatNames()) {
                if (list.toString().contains(string)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        public BufferedImage toBufferedImage(Image image) {
            if (image instanceof BufferedImage) {
                return (BufferedImage) image;
            }
            image = new ImageIcon(image).getImage();
            boolean hasAlpha = hasAlpha(image);
            BufferedImage bimage = null;
            GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
            int transparency = Transparency.OPAQUE;
            if (hasAlpha == true) {
                transparency = Transparency.BITMASK;
            }
            GraphicsDevice gs = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
            GraphicsConfiguration gc = gs.getDefaultConfiguration();
            bimage = gc.createCompatibleImage(image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null), transparency);
            if (bimage == null) {
                int type = BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB;
                if (hasAlpha == true) {
                    type = BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB;
                }
                bimage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null), type);
            }
            Graphics g = bimage.createGraphics();
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
            g.dispose();
            return bimage;
        }

        public boolean hasAlpha(Image image) {
            if (image instanceof BufferedImage) {
                return ((BufferedImage) image).getColorModel().hasAlpha();
            }
            PixelGrabber pg = new PixelGrabber(image, 0, 0, 1, 1, false);
            try {
                pg.grabPixels();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            return pg.getColorModel().hasAlpha();
        }

        private void updateRectangle(int compWidth, int compHeight) {
            int x = currentRect.x;
            int y = currentRect.y;
            int width = currentRect.width;
            int height = currentRect.height;
            if (width < 0) {
                width = 0 - width;
                x = x - width + 1;
                if (x < 0) {
                    width += x;
                    x = 0;
                }
            }
            if (height < 0) {
                height = 0 - height;
                y = y - height + 1;
                if (y < 0) {
                    height += y;
                    y = 0;
                }
            }
            if ((x + width) > compWidth) {
                width = compWidth - x;
            }
            if ((y + height) > compHeight) {
                height = compHeight - y;
            }
            if (rectToDraw != null) {
                rectToDraw.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
            } else {
                rectToDraw = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
            }
        }

        public void capture() {
            BufferedImage croppedImage = origiImage.getSubimage(rectToDraw.x, rectToDraw.y, rectToDraw.width, rectToDraw.height);
            setSize(rectToDraw.width, rectToDraw.height);
            image = croppedImage;

            currentRect = null;

            repaint();
        }

        public void upload(BufferedImage image) {
          // Sorry, you can uncomment this can't you
//        String IMGUR_POST_URI = "http://api.imgur.com/2/upload.xml";
//        String IMGUR_API_KEY = "b84e430b4a65d16a6955358141f21a61";
//        String readLine = null;
//        try {
//            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
//            ImageIO.write(image, "png", outputStream);
//            URL url = new URL(IMGUR_POST_URI);
//
//            String data = URLEncoder.encode("image", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Base64.encodeBase64String(outputStream.toByteArray()).toString(), "UTF-8") + "&" + URLEncoder.encode("key", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(IMGUR_API_KEY, "UTF-8");
//
//            URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
//            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
//            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
//            wr.write(data);
//            wr.flush();
//            // Get the response
//            InputStream inputStream;
//            if (((HttpURLConnection) urlConnection).getResponseCode() == 400) {
//                inputStream = ((HttpURLConnection) urlConnection).getErrorStream();
//            } else {
//                inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
//            }
//            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
//            String line;
//            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
//                readLine = line;
//            }
//            wr.close();
//            reader.close();
//        } catch (Exception e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }
//        //Prints the url link of the image uploaded
//        System.out.println(readLine.substring(readLine.indexOf("<original>") + 10, readLine.indexOf("</original>")));
        }

        public void dragEnter(DropTargetDragEvent dtde) {
        }

        public void dragExit(DropTargetEvent dte) {
        }

        public void dragOver(DropTargetDragEvent dtde) {
        }

        public void dropActionChanged(DropTargetDragEvent dtde) {
        }

        protected class CaptureListener extends MouseInputAdapter {

            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                updateSize(e);
            }

            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

                requestFocusInWindow();

                int x = e.getX();
                int y = e.getY();
                currentRect = new Rectangle(x, y, 0, 0);
                updateRectangle(getWidth(), getHeight());
                repaint();
            }

            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                updateSize(e);
            }

            public void updateSize(MouseEvent e) {
                if (currentRect != null) {
                    currentRect.setSize(e.getX() - currentRect.x, e.getY() - currentRect.y);
                    updateRectangle(getWidth(), getHeight());
                    repaint();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now it works...

Answer (score 0):

## Quick answer

The problem you asked about was that the window decorations (the "frame", titlebar etc.) cover parts of the cropped image. (That's why I thought comparing with expected results or the result uploaded/saved to file might help).

In terms of a solution you basically have to ensure that you do not resize the window as by its outer boundaries, but give the content the space needed. There are several ways to do that. MadProgrammer moved most of your code to a panel class and added an instance of that as the JFrame's content.

Alternatively you could keep using the JFrame contentPane and just ensure that you set the size on it instead of the frame:

```
getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(newWidth, newHeight));
pack();
```

(methods are called on your JFrame instance, the solution works from Java 5 on)

---

## Finding the answer yourself

The image cropping itself is fine. Your problem lies somewhere else and I want to help you find it yourself.

### Minimize the problem

You have to narrow down where in your code the "strange things" happen. So do not stare at all your code but make a copy and, as a first step throw out what is not needed for the cropping.
Throw out the upload stuff, you don't need it for cropping.
A lot of your code deals with getting a filename by drag and drop. Shorten it down to either a command line option or a plain hardcoded string (hardcoded stuff is bad in general, but for debugging it's okay). And so on.

Actually cropping does not need any GUI, really. So what happens if you write your cropped image to a file instead of displaying it in a window?

### Know what to expect

GUI or not, put out the position(x,y) and dimension(width,height) of your selection. Now, how does the image cropped by your program compare to the same image cropped with the same parameters using gimp/ImageMagick/... ? Which parts of the image are missing?

### Ask good questions

Following those steps and asking such questions, you should know what's wrong with your program. At the very least you will be able to ask a short and precise question about your problem. And on StackOverflow there will probably be someone who can answer it!

Comment: The problem is, I've been debugging it for several hours now, and cant seem to find what's wrong with it.